# Using DISTINCT along with GROUP BY in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, distinct

Is there any purpose for using both DISTINCT and GROUP BY in SQL?

Below is a sample code

```
SELECT DISTINCT Actors
FROM MovieDetails
GROUP BY Actors
```

Does anyone know of any situations where both DISTINCT and GROUP BY need to be used, to get any specific desired results?

(The general usage of DISTINCT and GROUP BY separately is understood)

Comment: You can use it together in `SELECT ..., COUNT(DISTINCT ...) FROM ... GROUP BY ...`. In your case it is pointless

Comment: no, you can drop the `DISTINCT`, it's redundant

Comment: `group by` delivers `distinct` results. What use could there be to add it? Think about it

Comment: A few weeks back, I was browsing through some articles and came across some discussion about some special use-case for this. I couldn't find that article again. Hence, I thought I would post it here!
But I get the idea that it is redundant to use both in almost all cases!

Comment: One or the other or both you get the same query plan and the same results. Test for yourself.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

#### Use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicate `GROUPING SETS` from the `GROUP BY` clause

In a completely silly example using `GROUPING SETS()` in general (or the special grouping sets `ROLLUP()` or `CUBE()` in particular), you could use `DISTINCT` in order to remove the duplicate values produced by the grouping sets again:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT actors
FROM (VALUES('a'), ('a'), ('b'), ('b')) t(actors)
GROUP BY CUBE(actors, actors)
```

With `DISTINCT`:

```
actors
------
NULL
a
b
```

Without `DISTINCT`:

```
actors
------
a
b
NULL
a
b
a
b
```

But why, apart from making an academic point, would you do that?

#### Use `DISTINCT` to find unique aggregate function values

In a less far-fetched example, you might be interested in the `DISTINCT` aggregated values, such as, how many *different* duplicate numbers of actors are there?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*)
FROM (VALUES('a'), ('a'), ('b'), ('b')) t(actors)
GROUP BY actors
```

Answer:

```
count
-----
2
```

#### Use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates with more than one `GROUP BY` column

Another case, of course, is this one:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT actors, COUNT(*)
FROM (VALUES('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('b', 2)) t(actors, id)
GROUP BY actors, id
```

With `DISTINCT`:

```
actors  count
-------------
a       2
b       1
```

Without `DISTINCT`:

```
actors  count
-------------
a       2
b       1
b       1
```

For more details, I've written some blog posts, e.g. [about `GROUPING SETS` and how they influence the `GROUP BY` operation](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/04/do-you-really-understand-sqls-group-by-and-having-clauses/), or [about the logical order of SQL operations (as opposed to the lexical order of operations)](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/).

Comment: To further the example you could also say Select Distinct ... FROM ... GROUP BY...  HAVING...  or find distinct ... from table with some aggregate condition

Comment: @BradD: I thought of the same thing, but I couldn't think of a case where `HAVING` changes anything.

Comment: Last example is the same as **`SELECT actors
FROM (VALUES('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('b', 2)) t(actors, id)
GROUP BY actors`** so why need distinct?

Comment: Find distinct actors with more than one ID? there are other ways of getting there, but its for example sake

Comment: @LukasEder Maybe, but I would rather use `SELECT actors, COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM (VALUES('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('b', 2)) t(actors, id) GROUP BY actors`

Comment: @lad2025: That yields an entirely different result

Answer (score 5):

I would group by in a `subselect` and then take the distinct in the select statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (  SELECT Actors
        FROM MovieDetails
        GROUP BY Actors
    ) d
```

Comment: Could you explain why? The grouping is already unique.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not in the context that you have it, but you could use

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1,
PERCENTILE_CONT(col2) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col2) OVER (PARTITION BY col1),
PERCENTILE_CONT(col2) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col2) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col3),
FROM TableA
```

You would use this to return different levels of aggregation returned in a single row.  The use case would be for when a single grouping would not suffice all of the aggregates needed.

Comment: **`OVER (PARTITION BY)`**? Not `GROUP BY`

Comment: Although note that there's no `GROUP BY` in your main clause so this is technically not the case that was being asked about.