# Selecting distinct values within a a group

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, toad, distinct-values

I want to select distinct values of one variable within a group defined by another variable. What is the easiest way?
My first thought was to combine group by and distinct but it does not work. I tried something like:

```
select distinct col2, col1 from myTable
group by col1
```

I have looked at this one here but can't seem to solve my problem
[Using DISTINCT along with GROUP BY in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32702310/using-distinct-along-with-group-by-in-sql-server#_=)_

**Table example**

[image]

Comment: I am using Toad and working with Oracle databases

Comment: That link is for really advanced GROUP BY tricks. Something you do every 5th year or so.

Comment: GROUP BY is intended to be used with set functions, like MAX(), SUM() etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your requirement is to pick distinct combinations if col1 and COL2 then no need to group by just use

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE1;
```

But if you want to group by then automatically one record per group is displayed by then you have to use aggregate function of one of the columns i.e.

```
SELECT COL1, COUNT(COL2)
FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY COL1;
```

Answer (score 2):

no need group by just use distinct

```
select distinct col2, col1 from myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table t as
with inputs(val, id) as
(
    select 'A', 1 from dual union all
    select 'A', 1 from dual union all
    select 'A', 2 from dual union all
    select 'B', 1 from dual union all
    select 'B', 2 from dual union all
    select 'C', 3 from dual 
)
select * from inputs;
```

The above creates your table and the below is the solution (12c and later):

```
select * from t
match_recognize
(
    partition by val
    order by id
    all rows per match 
    pattern ( a {- b* -} )
    define b as val = a.val and id = a.id
);
```

Output:

[image]

Regards,
Ranagal

Comment: Thanks. I need to read up on match_recognize and partition by. Can't figure out wahts going on by lookin at the code, but it workds for me !