# Combine data with same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an assignment where I need to use aggregate functions in the queries. I keep running into a problem where there are multiply entries for the same ID, and I would rather them be combined into one run (added together for the same ID).

```
-- Aggregate #3 - Show the total amount of pledges for each Team 
-- for particular year.   Order the results by amount of pledges highest 
-- to lowest.  This query should result in 1 row per Team.  
-- It should include the Team ID, Team name (or a combination of Sport, 
-- Level, and Gender), the total pledge amount and the Event date/year.

SELECT DISTINCT SUM(TEGS.monPledgeAmount) AS TotalPledge
  ,TE.intEventID
  ,TTC.intTeamandClubID
  ,TE.dtmEventDate
  ,TGS.strGenderDesc
  ,TLT.strLevelDesc
FROM TEventGolfers AS TEG JOIN TEvents TE
    ON TEG.intEventID = TE.intEventID

JOIN TGolfers AS TG
    ON TG.intGenderID = TEG.intGolferID

JOIN TEventGolferSponsors AS TEGS
    ON TEGS.intEventGolferID = TEG.intEventGolferID

JOIN TEventGolferTeamandClubs AS TEGTC
    ON TEGTC.intEventGolferID = TEG.intEventGolferID

JOIN TTeamandClubs AS TTC
    ON TTC.intTeamandClubID = TEGTC.intTeamandClubID

JOIN TLevelofTeams AS TLT
    ON TLT.intLevelofTeamID = TTC.intLevelofTeamID

JOIN TGenders AS TGS
    ON TGS.intGenderID = TTC.intGenderID


GROUP BY
    TEGS.monPledgeAmount
   ,TE.intEventID
   ,TTC.intTeamandClubID
   ,TE.dtmEventDate
   ,TGS.strGenderDesc
   ,TLT.strLevelDesc
```

Output below (IDs to be combined in column 3, "intTeamandClubID"):

```
0.80    2   3   2016-01-01  Female  Varsity Football
0.80    2   4   2016-01-01  Male    Varsity Golf
4.00    2   3   2016-01-01  Female  Varsity Football
4.00    2   4   2016-01-01  Male    Varsity Golf
10.00   2   3   2016-01-01  Female  Varsity Football
50.00   2   3   2016-01-01  Female  Varsity Football
```

I want the "intTeamandClubID" to be 1 row for the same ID, and the "TotalPledge" to be added together.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: As per the [*How to ask* guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/251362#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Hint: if you only want each`intTeamandClubID` and its total, don't select anything else.

Comment: Updated the post with the question so it's more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the **DISTINCT** in the **SELECT** clause and the column **TEGS.monPledgeAmount** in the **GROUP BY** clause.

```
SELECT SUM(TEGS.monPledgeAmount) AS TotalPledge
  ,TE.intEventID
  ,TTC.intTeamandClubID
  ,TE.dtmEventDate
  ,TGS.strGenderDesc
  ,TLT.strLevelDesc
FROM TEventGolfers AS TEG JOIN TEvents TE
    ON TEG.intEventID = TE.intEventID

JOIN TGolfers AS TG
    ON TG.intGenderID = TEG.intGolferID

JOIN TEventGolferSponsors AS TEGS
    ON TEGS.intEventGolferID = TEG.intEventGolferID

JOIN TEventGolferTeamandClubs AS TEGTC
    ON TEGTC.intEventGolferID = TEG.intEventGolferID

JOIN TTeamandClubs AS TTC
    ON TTC.intTeamandClubID = TEGTC.intTeamandClubID

JOIN TLevelofTeams AS TLT
    ON TLT.intLevelofTeamID = TTC.intLevelofTeamID

JOIN TGenders AS TGS
    ON TGS.intGenderID = TTC.intGenderID


GROUP BY
    
   TE.intEventID
   ,TTC.intTeamandClubID
   ,TE.dtmEventDate
   ,TGS.strGenderDesc
   ,TLT.strLevelDesc
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to sum the `TotalPledge` values for each `intTeamandClubID`. For that you would need to create a different group for each `intTeamandClubID`. In your case, since you are selecting multiple columns, you will create a group for each unique combination of those columns, which is done by a [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql) statement.

You already have that in your query, but you are also grouping by `TotalPledge`, which you don't want. You want to SUM that value, so you should remove it from the `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY
   TE.intEventID
   ,TTC.intTeamandClubID
   ,TE.dtmEventDate
   ,TGS.strGenderDesc
   ,TLT.strLevelDesc
```

Note that, even though it [has some use-cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32702834/12162243) alongside GROUP BY, `DISTINCT` is unnecessary here since each group (combination of columns values) is unique. Leaving it in the query, however, won't impact the result